# Is it ok to say "put on" as an order to a pupil when it comes to opening an electronic dictionary on an iPad or any other electronic divice?

Tags: word-choice

I was studying with my sister and I told her to look up some words and as she´s got an iPad I told her "go to the Oxford Lerarner's dictionary and look for ...." which I think is right, but I wonder if there is another way or phrasal verb to say that very same thing.

What about "Put on the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary on your iPad and look for......
Do I have to make it clear it has to be open on her iPad or the noun can be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Put on" isn't used like this.  think the most commonly used verb is "**Open the app**," or sometimes "Go to the app," or the more specific action "Click on the app"/"Tap on the app."

You can certainly omit "on your iPad"/"on your tablet"/"on your device." But apps and programs are always **on** devices, not in them.